# Choosing Next Tab on clicking a Button jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, salesforce, visualforce

Hi i am writing a visualforce page code is

```
<apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->

  <head>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.UIJQuery1822, 'js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')}"/>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQueryMin}" />
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.UIJQuery1822,'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css')}" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j( "#tabset" ).tabs();
        $j('#theButton').click(function() {
            var selected = $("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected");
            $("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
            // $( "#tabset" ).tabs( 'select' , 2 );
            // alert('Hello World')
        });
    });
    </script>

  <Title>Hello World</Title></head>
  <Body>
  <div id="tabset">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#panel1">Tab One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel2">Tab Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel3">Tab Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="panel1"> Hello World1</div>
  <div id="panel2">Hello World2
  <button type="button" id="theButton">Click Me!</button></div>
  <div id="panel3">Hello World3 </div>

  </div>
  </Body>

</apex:page>
```

what i have to accomplish is when i click Click me it will activate Tab Three.there are two comment lines in click function when i comment out alert('Hello World') its giving me alert but when i comment alert line and use any one option its not activating the 3rd tab.can any please tell me Why its not activating third tab?? and give some code snippet such that it starts working fine!!

Comment: `$j('#theButton').click(function()` replace with `$('#theButton').click(function()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabset" ).tabs();
    $('#theButton').click(function() {
        var selected = $("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    });
});
```

it works

IF you are having a name issue, you can do:

```
(function($) { 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabset").tabs();
    $('#theButton').click(function() {
        $('#showem').text("howdy");

        var selected = $("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
     });

});
})(jQuery);
```

This passes the jQuery into the wrapped function.

To use YOUR $j name do:

```
(function($j) { 
    $j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#tabset").tabs();
    $j('#theButton').click(function() {
        $j('#showem').text("howdy");

        var selected = $j("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected");
        $j("#tabset").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
     });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First change:**
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
**To:**
jQuery.noConflict();

From now on you will use **jQuery** instead of the **$** so to call functions use: `jQuery('').hide();`

It does not make sense to call noConflit and keep using $.